# Chapter numbers being added to List of Figures etc

Tags: sectioning

I am using a thesis template, which can be [downloaded here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

I need to format my chapter titles like this:

**Chapter 1. Chapter Title**

I can achieve this with this code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\LARGE\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.\space}
```

But this adds chapter numbers to all front matter sections like this:

**Chapter 0. List of Figures**

**Chapter 0. List of Tables**

**Chapter 0. Contents**

How can I remove Chapter 0 from the front matter sections?

Comment: You have been here a while: How about a MWE, such that users don't to follow links an download this and that? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently use `titlesec`. You have to define two versions of `\titleformat`. One for ordinary (numbered) chapters, and one for unnumbered chapters, with the `numberless` key. By the way, for such centred titles, you should use the `block`style. If I understand well what you want to do, change your code to these lines in your preamble:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[block]{\centering\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}{0.5em}{}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\centering\LARGE\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
```

You will probably have to redo the formatting of the table of contents if you want unnumbered chapters to appear in it. This can easily be done with the companion package `titletoc`.